# python unpack a dict from json

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary, turbogears2

I've been searching around, but I cannot find an answer, my guess is that my question is not defined very well, so i hope to get some guidance

I'm using turbogears2.2
I'm sending from the client view a JavaScript object through $.post(),
On the server I receive this object (as kw):

```
{'phones[1][surname]': u'sym', 'phones[2][name]': u'', 'phones[1][phone]': u'5498498', 'phones[0][phone]': u'0564', 'phones[1][name]': u'jhon', 'phones[0][surname]': u'cat', 'phones[2][phone]': u'', 'phones[0][name]': u'bob'}
```

I'm sending a data from a table with 3 columns

On my server I'm trying to separate the data for each row, but I'm a bit lost here.
how can I split that dict into different rows of data?

Doing

```
import json
json.loads(str(kw))
```

Fails

```
{ValueError}: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

How can I convert that dict/object to a nested dictionary (or something else)?
Thanks

Comment: You didn't post JSON; you posted `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data that jQuery formatted for the PHP array feature.

Comment: Do show us your JavaScript (jQuery) code that does the posting.

Comment: I'v added an answer, Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) , I thought I was posting JSON, but i wasn't.

> You didn't post JSON; you posted application/x-www-form-urlencoded data that jQuery formatted for the PHP array feature. –  Martijn Pieters

Here is my JavaScript, I'm trying out [HandsOnTable](http://handsontable.com/) (jQuery data grid editor)

```
$("#sendToServer").click(function(){
        var tableData = $("#myTable").data('handsontable');
        $.post(
            URL,
            {phones:tableData.getData()},
            function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }
        )
    })
```

And that wasn't JSON, even though I thought it was

Anyway, simple fix:

Client side (JavaScript):

```
var tableData = $("#myTable").data('handsontable');
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(tableData.getData())
...
$.post(URL,
     {phones:jsonData},
...
)
```

And now on the server side (Python):

```
import json
def getPhones(self,**kw):
        phones = json.loads(kw['phones'])
        ...
```

And I have the data as a dict of rows, great

Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

To post *JSON*, don't use `$.post()`. Use `$.ajax()` instead, and set the content type explicitly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({phone: tableData.getData()}),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(response);
    },
});
```

This can especially help if you have a controller that handles JSON directly, such as those provided by [TurboGears Web Services](http://pythonhosted.org/TGWebServices/).